# i want to make multiple columns a single column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have columns A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3,B4 and I want to correlate group A with group B. I want to make columns with A single column and columns with B as single column.

```
library(tidyverse)

aml_values <- CTL %>% 
  select(AML.1, AML.2, AML.3, AML.4, AML.5, AML.6, AML.7, AML.8) %>%
  unlist() 

normal_values <- CTL %>% 
  select(Normal.1, Normal.2, Normal.3, Normal.4) %>% 
  unlist()
```

I tried to collect them under one column by doing this but I'm not sure

Comment: See `tidyr::unite()`

Comment: The description and code provided do not match. Please provide minimal reproducible data as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example